# Cannot send message to group in SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller, signalr

So I have the below code, which I am trying to make it send the message when I join the group, but it is not working

```
   public async Task JoinGroup()
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "Hello");
            await Clients.Group("Hello").SendAsync("SEND", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has been added");
        }
```

When I try it like this

```
  public async Task JoinGroup()
        {
            await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "Hello"); 
            await Clients.All.SendAsync("SEND", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has been added");
        }
```

It works, but it sends the message to all the connected clients, which I do not want to happen.

I got the first code block from the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/groups?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Anyone have any idea why it is not working?

Edit:
I have a listener in the front

```
 connection.on("SEND", message => alert(message))
```

Comment: It looks like you are adding every connection to the same group,

Comment: I get the name from a parameter, but I was just doing that to test if it works like that, but no luck @spzvtbg

Comment: *When I try it like this ... `Clients.All.Send...` ... it sends the message to all the connected clients* - er..

Comment: @CaiusJard, I'm sorry I do not understand, i get that you are quoting what I said, but the er.., I dont get

Comment: What does "not working" mean?

Comment: @CaiusJard it is not sending the message, I've added the js part where I listen for it, with All it works, it displays an alert with the message ''{Context.ConnectionId} has been added", but when I switch to groups, the listener never gets hit

Answer (score 0):

For sending message in group, should use .Group instead .All.

```
    await Clients.Group.SendAsync("SEND", $"{Context.ConnectionId} has been added");
```